# .NET Grpc unit test CallContext

Tags: .net, grpc, grpc-c#

I am using the packages `Grpc.Core` and `ProtoBuf.Grpc` because I want to use both: Code-First gRPC with gRPC ClientFactory.
Now I have an interface of form `Task<Response> MyMethod(Request request, CallContext context)` with `CallContext` coming from `ProtoBuf.Grpc`.

In the implementation of the interface I get the authorized (calling) user like this:

```
var user = httpContext.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I want to unit test my implementation of `MyMethod` but I do not know how to create the correct context for `CallContext` with a test user.

How can I test my implementation `MyMethod` with a predefined user in the `CallContext`?

**Edit:**

It seems possible to create and pass an instance of `CallContext` by calling the constructor

```
public CallContext(object server, ServerCallContext context)
```

I can create the `ServerCallContext` object via `TestServerCallContext.Create()`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/test-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0).
However I do not know what to pass for `object server`. Does anyone have an example for me?

Comment: Never mind, anything except `null` goes for `object server`, e.g. `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unit testing `gRPC` with authentication and user context the following approach was my solution:

```
public static ProtoBuf.Grpc.CallContext TestCallContext(Guid user)
{
    var serverCallContext = TestServerCallContext.Create(
                                            method: nameof(IGrpcGreetingService.Greeting)
                                        , host: "localhost"
                                        , deadline: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
                                        , requestHeaders: new Metadata()
                                        , cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None
                                        , peer: "10.0.0.25:5001"
                                        , authContext: null
                                        , contextPropagationToken: null
                                        , writeHeadersFunc: (metadata) => Task.CompletedTask
                                        , writeOptionsGetter: () => new WriteOptions()
                                        , writeOptionsSetter: (writeOptions) => { }
                                        );

    var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "some subject"),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name, user.ToString())
        };
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    httpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
    serverCallContext.UserState["__HttpContext"] = httpContext;

    return new ProtoBuf.Grpc.CallContext("", serverCallContext);
}
```

With arguments for `TestServerCallContext.Create` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67121378/trying-to-implement-grpc-unit-test-for-c-sharp).

Maybe this can help somebody else save some hours or days :)